# Wordpress Gutenberg File Buttons - How to display first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom

I'm trying to display the buttons from the gutenberg editor before the actual document name. Right now the buttons are displayed after the title, as a second child of the "**wp-block-file**".

I've tried several approaches:

- `jQuery(".wp-block-file__button").append(".wp-block-file");`
  Didn't work out. It just breaks the structure.
- `jQuery(".wp-block-file:last-child").append(".wp-block-file");`
  Same here.
- `let button = jQuery(".wp-block-file__button");
  button.before("a.wp-block-file");`
  Didn't work out.

Does anyone know a good method to achieve the requested result? Any help is highly appreciated!

Edit:
Example the displayed Gutenberg File-Download-Buttons

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21npn.png)

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would be nice

Comment: @niklas thanks for your reply! I've updated my post with a screenshot.

Comment: It looks like on the frontend? Then it is a theme issue, you can tackle with css. If you give an url or actual code that is output, people can help you. And please: try to be clear about what you are asking. Your question does not seem gutenberg related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flexbox and add this css

```
.wp-block-file {
display:flex;
}
.wp-block-file a:nth-child(1) {
order: 2;
}
.wp-block-file a:nth-child(2) {
order: 1;
}
```